# How to store an array(of strings) in phpMyAdmin

Tags: codeigniter, phpmyadmin

is there a way to store an array in phpMyAdmin.

I know there are probably a few but I was wondering which would be the best with CodeIgniter.

My issue is I want to add the data via CodeIgniter Model and I can't find any reference about arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all phpmyadmin isnt where the data is stored, phpmyadmin is an interface for mySQL databases.
http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

That being said, mySQL databases cannot store 'an array', only datatypes such as ints, strings, datetimes etc

A possible solution is to covert your array of strings into one long string ([php -implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)) and store it as a single string in your database.

Then when you pull it out of the database, separate it back into an array of strings ([php str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php))

Comment: Thanks .. Nice Answer. On a side note could I connect phpMyAdmin to Oracle DB and then use a vArray?

Comment: I have very limited knowledge of oracle so I'm hesitant to comment on that, although is changing your databases in such a way a better option than some crafty string manipulation? I'm not so sure

Comment: It would be better to store the array as JSON then imploding it though